# How to change GRUB2's keyboard layout on a laptop?

Tags: grub2, keyboard-layout, laptop

This question has often been asked, and all the answers I could find involve setting `GRUB_TERMINAL_INPUT=at_keyboard` in `/etc/default/grub` (see for example https://askubuntu.com/questions/751259/how-to-change-grub-command-line-grub-shell-keyboard-layout). Now, [like a commentator said](https://askubuntu.com/questions/751259/how-to-change-grub-command-line-grub-shell-keyboard-layout#answer-1391658) this usually doesn't work on laptops. I tested on both a Dell and an Asus laptop, it doesn't work (I also tested in a VM, and it works fine). In fact it renders the keyboard completely unusable on both my laptops.

According [to GRUB's documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Simple-configuration.html), `GRUB_TERMINAL_INPUT` can take 4 values : `console`, `serial`, `at_keyboard` and `usb_keyboard`. So I tried to set `GRUB_TERMINAL_INPUT=usb_keyboard` and plugged a USB keyboard into the laptop. But the keyboard remains in QWERTY.

I did a few other interesting tests from within Grub console :

```
grub> terminal_input
Active input terminals:
console
Available input terminals:
serial_* serial at_keyboard
```

Despite what's stated [in Grub's documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Simple-configuration.html), `usb_keyboard` isn't among the available input terminals. Also note that a USB keyboard was indeed plugged into the laptop when I launched that command, and that keyboard was working (although still in QWERTY).

```
grub> terminal_input at_keyboard
grub>
```

That command disables completely all my keyboards (both the integrated laptop keyboard and the USB keyboard), which confirms the fact that `at_keyboard` is not working at all on laptops (or at least on my 2 laptops).

**So, my question is :**

Does anybody know of a method to change GRUB2's keyboard layout **that works on laptops** ? Or can someone confirm that maybe it simply is not possible ?

Note : Grub version 2.06 (Debian 11.6)

[EDIT]
According to [Suse's documentation](https://documentation.suse.com/sled/15-SP4/html/SLED-all/cha-grub2.html#sec-grub2-menu-change) :

> The US keyboard layout is the only one available when booting

Which is obviously false (at least partially), because the keyboard layout can be changed using `GRUB_TERMINAL_INPUT=at_keyboard` (except on laptops)